# How to NOT write to depth buffer?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a background I can tilt (vertical rotation) as-needed. I have a cube map. If I use the built-in `scene.background = texture` then I won't be able to tilt it. If I use a box (or sphere) geometry, it'll move, but it needs to stay still.

This post: 
[Tilt three.js background or tilt HDRI image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518346/tilt-three-js-background-or-tilt-hdri-image) suggests *not writing to the depth buffer*. How do you *not* write to the depth buffer?

Answer (score 1):

```
material.depthWrite = false;
```

[see docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.depthWrite)